# Loop by IP Address

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I have a working code to check the house for the ram amount on each unit. I give it an IP address and it returns the amount of ram and a few other things all nicely formatted. Can I just add a pre-done file into this to get it to accept an IP list from either .txt or .csv?

I've tried piecing this code I have in another file that runs off the list but I keep getting errors.

```
param([string]$fileInput,[string]$fileOutput )

If ( $fileInput -eq "" -OR $fileOutput -eq ""){ 
    $list =  Import-Csv $fileInput -Header name, licenseKey, keyStatus

    foreach( $computerName in $list){
          export-csv -InputObject $computerName -append $fileOutput -Encoding utf8
    }
}
```

I'm not sure the right placement for these lines in my code.

```
write-host ""
$strComputer = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name to list memory slot information"
$colSlots = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemoryArray" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computerName $strComputer
$colRAM = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computerName $strComputer
$NumSlots = 0

write-host ""
$colSlots | ForEach {
  “Total Number of Memory Slots: ” + $_.MemoryDevices
  $NumSlots = $_.MemoryDevices
}

write-host ""
Read-Host "Press Enter to continue"

$SlotsFilled = 0
$TotMemPopulated = 0

$colRAM | ForEach {
   “Memory Installed: ” + $_.DeviceLocator
   “Memory Size: ” + ($_.Capacity / 1GB) + ” GB”       
   $SlotsFilled = $SlotsFilled + 1
   $TotMemPopulated = $TotMemPopulated + ($_.Capacity / 1GB)
#      if ($_.Capacity = 0)
#      {write-host "found free slot"}

}

write-host ""
write-host "=== Summary Memory Slot Info for computer:" $strComputer "==="
write-host ""
If (($NumSlots - $SlotsFilled) -eq 0) {
    write-host "ALL Slots Filled, NO EMPTY SLOTS AVAILABLE!"
}
write-host ($NumSlots - $SlotsFilled) " of " $NumSlots " slots Open/Available (Unpopulated)"
write-host ($SlotsFilled) " of " $NumSlots " slots Used/Filled (Populated)."  
write-host ""
write-host "Total Memory Populated = " $TotMemPopulated "GB"

#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6) loop would be idiomatic solution.

Create a text file that contains computer names or IP addresses like this:

```
computer1
computer2
...
computern
```

That is, each system name or address in its own row without anything extra. Simple enough, right? Save it as, say, `c:\temp\computersToCheck.txt`. After you've got a list of names, change the code to support aforementioned `foreach` loop.

```
# Read all the computers from the file
$computers = get-content c:\temp\computersToCheck.txt

# Perform an operation for each row in the file
foreach ($strComputer in $computers) {
    $colSlots = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemoryArray" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computerName $strComputer
    # Rest of the code goes here
...
write-host "Total Memory Populated = " $TotMemPopulated "GB"
}
```